Chrome does not open a new tab when starting a project in Visual Studio (2019 and 2022)
I have a project here, and in its debug settings, it is configured to open a new tab when the project starts. project config
When I set any browser other than Chrome, it opens a new tab normally, but when I configure Chrome specifically, it simply does not open the tab.
I’ve seen some suggestions to disable these parameters below, but none of them worked.
parameters1
parameters2

@hunteradv. Did you restart Visual Studio after updating the above settings? Restart Visual Studio if you made any changes.
Try clearing Chrome’s cache or resetting Chrome settings to their default.
And you could see if the following solution works for you.
launchSettings.json has an inspectUri:
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:57110",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "inspectUri": "{wsProtocol}://{url.hostname}:{url.port}/_framework/debug/ws-proxy?browser={browserInspectUri}",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}

If inspectUri property was removed, it will open a new tab instead of a window. However, the debugging symbols are not loaded and you cannot set breakpoints and debug your code. The symbols are loaded if I keep the launchUri and I use the Chrome window instead.
For more details you can also see the link.

Yes, I restarted Visual Studio, and just to be sure, I also deleted the .vs folder to regenerate it.
Additionally, I reset Chrome as well, but it didn’t solve the issue.
About the launchSettings, I don’t believe it’s a project-specific issue because other people on the team are using the same project and no one else has had or is having this problem. :(
But, yeah, my launchSettings dont have the inspectUri, but here I have applicationUrl defined, like this "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5067"

Since other team members are not facing this issue, this could be due to some configuration or system specific issue. 1. Verify that Chrome is selected as the default browser in Visual Studio 2. Make sure the ports being used (e.g. 2630, 5067, etc.) are not being used by other services or blocked by a firewall. 3. Try launching Visual Studio as an administrator.
